# FTP is not working in one my client machine?

Tags: windows, ftp, iis

I have setup FTP in IIS. It is working on all machines except for one client who is complaining that FTP is not working. When he opens FTP via a browser, he is not prompted to enter his credentials.

Comment: It sounds like a firewall setting on that machine.

Comment: have you cleared the bad browsers cookies/cache, and flushed any saved passwords?

Comment: @FrankThomas, It's new FTP service. So nothing will be in the cookie for that site.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, Thanks I will check and let you know

Comment: We really need more details in order to help you with this issue.   Is this FTP site internal (meaning only accessible via your LAN) or is it externally accessible?   What client(s) do you usually use to connect to FTP?  What is everyone else who can connect using?   If the client is external from the ftp server (over the internet), the most likely culprit will be PASV (passive) mode in combination with dynamic port forwarding.   Is this standard FTP over port 21 or are you using a custom FTP port?   This is another common issue with protocols other than HTTP for non-technical people.

Comment: `When he opens FTP via a browser` Which browser? The answer is probably browser-dependent.

Comment: @Richie086, the FTP is public. Any client on public can access this. Yes this on Port 21

Comment: @Synetech, tested on Chrome and IE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When he opens FTP via a browser, he is not prompted to enter his credentials.

FTP links may be opening in *Internet* Explorer on his system as opposed to *Windows* Explorer.

Starting with IE 7, FTP links are handled by the browser directly and do not open an Windows "file" Explorer window.  The handling of FTP liks in IE 7+ is not what some casual Windows users expect, i.e. the credential pop up and a file explorer window that allows drag-drop of files do not appear.  IE 7+ tries to render the FTP site in a browser window, allowing HTTP-like read-only access.

You should issue some instructions for your clients that tell your users to do the following:

- Press the Windows key + E (like Shift + E)
- A file explorer window will pop up.  Please copy and paste the FTP site address into this window
- You'll be prompted for credentials.  Enter them and then you can manipulate files as needed.

Another solution is to tell your client to download and install an FTP client such as FileZilla.  This may end up being easier than dealing with Windows weirdness with FTP links.

Keep in mind as well, while it is a security issue, you can specify the username and password as part of the FTP site address, i.e ftp://username:password@ftpsite.example.  Of course if you were concerned about security you wouldn't use FTP in the first place, so this may not matter.

Comment: Let see whether FileZilla solve this issue.